# How should I setup the "Users" area to hand over to a client?

Tags: admin, users, user-roles

We're about to hand over a Wordpress site to a client; this is the first one we've built from scratch.

Our "Users" area just consists boringly of the **admin** login with my work email like so:

[image].

What's the best way to set this up to hand over to the client? We want to retain the ability for us to login and support them and have full powers but not look like we still own it. As things stand, if we just add a couple of their members of staff to it now it'll still look like we're still the supreme user.

What do agencies normally do? This isn't a big project or client. They have a main person their end and a couple of junior users to help them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an admin level user for your client, preferably not one named
   "admin". If you track the number of attempted hacks on your site you
   will notice that most try to use the "admin" username.
2. Change the email for the admin use to reflect your client's email
   address
3. Or, preferably, delete the "admin" user and create another one with
   a less guessable name.

Comment: have done so ... created two fresh Administrator accounts one for them, and one new one for us ... and deleted the original "admin" ... seems obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

I adore using the [Advanced Access Manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/). Especially if you want to limit what your client can touch/edit and not touch/edit. You can limit their permissions as well. I for one do not like the idea of my clients having access to the Settings as they can easily change the permalinks and that can affect SEO for example. You should give it a look!

Comment: not sure a plugin is necessary for this simple setup ... but i'll take a look, thanks.